# How to edit .txt file with lists of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a .txt file containing lists of strings, a list per line:

```
['Animals', 'Endoplasmic Reticulum', 'Humans']
```

I want to edit each line, resembling something like this:

> training/197 animals endoplasmic reticulum humans

Where "training" is a variable I have previously assigned inside a function (i.e. this is to be ignored), "197" is the index of the line, and the following words are all the elements of the list in that line.

I'm not quite sure how to grab and "join" all of this (past the point of opening the file and having a for loop for each line), so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My abilities to read & understand what you want to accomplish is a bit limited, but do I understand you correctly if I think you have 3 problems;
`1.  You want to read in the list from the text-file as list & this will in the end generate a list of lists in python`
`2. For each list, you want to join the elements with some additions`
`3. Write the results to a file`

Please feel free to give feed back and possibly update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

for input file input.txt

```
['AAA', 'BBB CCC', 'DDD']
['EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG']
```

the outfile.txt is:

```
training/0 AAA BBB CCC DDD
training/1 EEE FFF GGG
```

code:

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file, open('outfile.txt','w') as out_file:
    row_index = 0
    any_string = 'training'
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        line_list = eval(line)
        final_row_string = '{}/{} {}\n'.format(any_string, row_index, str(' '.join(line_list)))
        out_file.write(final_row_string)
        row_index += 1
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said :

> "training" is a variable I have previously assigned inside a function
>   (i.e. this is to be ignored),

so i am only giving you solution for :

> I'm not quite sure how to grab and "join" all of this (past the point
>   of opening the file and having a for loop for each line):

You can try:

Its just ans example you can modify it according to your need :

```
import ast

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(*ast.literal_eval(line))
```

will give you output:

```
Animals Endoplasmic Reticulum Humans
```

you can check its type ,

```
print(type(ast.literal_eval(line)))
```

which is :

```
<class 'list'>
```

so you can do all list operation on this as per your requirement.